# Build URL from two form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, forms, url

Essentially, we have two form fields asking for users to supply us with two alphanumeric strings, and a URL needs to be constructed from the two. However, there is a basic structure to the URL that needs to be kept in place.

Users will input the requested numbers in two text fields on our site, then click a submit button. At that point the input data needs to be inserted into the URL and opened in their browser.

Example: URL.com/FixedData + UserEntry1 + FixedData + UserEntry2 –– UserEntry1 & UserEntry2 will be inserted between the fixed data.

The finished URL would appear as: `http://URL.com/FixedDataUserEntry1FixedDataUserEntry2`

Comment: What is your current form HTML/Javascript code looking like?

Comment: is this a question? thats the way to do it `var url = "url" + $("fd1")... + myFixedData + $("fd2")....`

Comment: This is my current code:
`<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://nolazombi.com/?ticket_launch=true&id=" + document.getElementById("url1").value + "&r_id=" + document.getElementByID("url2").value + "&html=true";
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>
<form onSubmit="return process();">
URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url1"><br />
Registration ID: <input type="text" name="url" id="url2"> <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>`

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your question.

**HTML**

```
<input id='UserEntry1' type='text'>
<input id='UserEntry2' type='text'>
```

**Javascript**

```
var URLBase = "http://URL.com/fixeddata1";
var TrailingFixedData = "fixeddata2";

finalURL = URLBase + document.getElementById('UserEntry1').value + TrailingFixedData + document.getElementById('UserEntry2').value;
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
finalURL = URLBase + $('#UserEntry1').val() + TrailingFixedData + $('#UserEntry2').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4M3q3/

HTML:

```
<input id="one"><input id="two">
<button id="open">Open</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    var fixedData1 = 'http://www.google.com/#q=',
        fixedData2 = '+',
        userEntry1 = $('#one').val(),
        userEntry2 = $('#two').val();

    var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + two, '_blank');
    newWindow.focus();
});
```

Comment: The URL is completely different than what he's asked for.  It's got nothing to do with querystring :)

Comment: @Archer This is exactly what he asked for. He wants to build a URL given some constant ('http://www.google.com/#q=' in my example), some user input, another constant ('+' in my example), and another piece of input. I showed how to get value of the user input, concatenate the pieces into a string, and open the URL. It doesn't matter if the URL has a query string or not, he'll just concatenate strings anyway. (The example Google URL doesn't have a query string, by the way.)

Comment: It's fixed now - it's all good :)